# Attaching an OnClick event to dynamically created React components

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a set of React components from JSON data. I'm trying to attach an OnClick function to each component, but it is not working.

In this example two dynamic components (Workers, renderWorkers) from JSON data and two hard-coded components (Worker, renderWorker) are created. The latter ones have working OnClick functions (selectWorker, doing console.log messages). I tried to attach the functions (selectWorker2) to components in a similar way.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-lichterman-b9npo?file=/src/index.js

Am I doing this totally wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the attached codesandbox, there's an mistake in the **Workers** component. There's no issue with JSON data part as you have suspected. 
In the **Workers** component, you have attempted both property destructuring (i.e,the portion that is within flower braces *{}* in the props) as well as props.
So in order to work, just change the code for Workers component from this,

```
const Workers = ({ i, worker }, props) => {
 ....
};
```

to

```
const Workers = ({ i, worker, onClick }) => {
 ....
};
```

or use simply **props** without *{}* like,

```
const Workers = (props) => {
...
}
```

For more information check [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that's a feature of javascript

Comment: Yes, now it is working, just with props. I probably had it like that before. Then I had a big fight with database and tried out a lot of different things with properties. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear :). Can you mark it as the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it in a function

i.e.,

```js
onClick={()=>{return props.onClick}}
```